# Animate Resize View in Material Design

Tags: android, resize, android-custom-view, material-design

Without involving layoutParams, is there another way to resize, collapse or expand a view? I saw that animations in some vieos of the new Material Design and in the new Android Dialer App. Google said Material can change shape, size, rotation, color, etc. easyly ... but I can't find anything.

Is there backwards compatibility?

Until now in order to resize, collapse or expand a view we had to work with layoutParams like this for example:

```
public static void collapse(final View v) {
final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

Animation a = new Animation()
{
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        if(interpolatedTime == 1){
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int)(initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
};

a.setDuration((int)(initialHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
v.startAnimation(a);
```

}

Here is an example of what I want from the new Google Android Dialer App:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I think ViewPropertyAnimator is what you want.
check this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#view-prop-animator﻿

Here is an example:

`view.animate().scaleY(endHeight/initialHeight).start()`

this is the same animation that you did in your code

Comment: Using `scaleY(..)` does not affect layout. Only the visible size of the item will change, but not the space taken by the view in the layout.

Comment: Yup, a `PropertyValuesHolder` would be a better option